# Image recognition of "Game Scenario" with deep learning

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, image-recognition

I know it may be a too board question... I have googled a lot, and find there are [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) for general object recognition, but the result is inaccurate for "Game Roles in Game Scenario".

I wonder is there any open source project, or commerce API, or procedures to do:

1. judge whether one picture is an Game Picture?
2. judge which Game it comes from if I could give some training data (labeled game pictures with game name) ?
3. detect which game role (maybe type, like it's a car but no need to tell it's BMW, but car is much better recognized) it has?

As I am new to this field, any suggestions are appreciated, I guess it's related with deep learning, I know Tensorflow/Theano/Torch but I never used them in image field before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can use deep-learning for this.

You could make your own model and train it for the tasks you want, or you can use an existing model.
For example, for image classification, you could train the inception model from google or the VGG-16 model.

I suggest you to use Keras, I find it easier to use than Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get some training images for each game, then you can use tensorflow for poets to classify.

In Tensorflow for poets, they have feature to create your own classes and train the Inception network on the classes that you have created using your own training samples.